# Creating a request to connect to WCF using SCT outside of .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

So basicly there is a WCF Service that I need to connect with but without using .NET.  The service is authenticated with a Client Certificate and seems to be using an SCT (I really don't have a great understanding of how this works).  I don't have access to the actually service configuration, I have been able to connect by adding a Service Reference in a C# project.

The Client Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="certificate">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://exampleService.com/myservice/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="certificate"
                contract="ExampleService.MyService" name="certificate" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior" />
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
            <clientCredentials>
              <clientCertificate findValue="44423325CCE18768B494FC0B519EB37CA" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"
                storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Example Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:8bc1a01c-4f7e-4599-99e2-40fae0b8aafd</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_1">https://exampleService.com/myservice/</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2014-05-16T19:16:20.666Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2014-05-16T19:21:20.666Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-b4d3baeb-f7e0-4745-8704-0ef9bcc4c2af-1" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">asdasadA2WhcNMTgxMTIwMDAwMDAwWjAUMRIwEAYDVQQDEwlsb2NhbGhvc3QwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBasdwIEsDATBgNVHSUEDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAvfHI7onOm7hzeT+S/JbpPqPj6Kvo+pZwJkdWQeTttcr+ZDHpeMK4viP6CgFhfasdasLVIn6ZmGE2i4Nsd8rMLBEUtfo6zj5fa2bN4sH5MlEfIBuBbdvkYEi9A0TLCFsGaKX2lEIJPPRnHLRVh8i+tlgeMQ3Tk0Sltg==</o:BinarySecurityToken>
         <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
               <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
               <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
               <Reference URI="#_0">
                  <Transforms>
                     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </Transforms>
                  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                  <DigestValue>Z0O5kEVzi34hgsvjOD4PtNx9PcY=</DigestValue>
               </Reference>
               <Reference URI="#_1">
                  <Transforms>
                     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </Transforms>
                  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                  <DigestValue>GcY5O34vlQQ+zkyjg0sMK9OVh8=</DigestValue>
               </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>YtCiPdshC5xdiLwasdasw1++asduJ0D378QWZcRZyEznbR6CzP9VrGO4e+GGMpPMD+Dd2swvbyPPJcnldMoDzShrfuUqRtzyM4cfysUa25WFIl5m7gQgxINtJ0F+u5b34b0SkHRQ1Covs6tro=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
               <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                  <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-b4d3b34eb-f7e0-4745-8704-0ef9bcc4c2af-1" />
               </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
         </Signature>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
         <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
         <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
         <t:Entropy>
            <t:BinarySecret u:Id="uuid-e6233483-73b-4f46-b4df-86d7d34943-1" Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">FpqyX6343qE7V0ULs9juwjJNAlMlxfdVXHnA0UU5I=</t:BinarySecret>
         </t:Entropy>
         <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
      </t:RequestSecurityToken>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Unfortunately, the requirements of this project don't allow me to use .NET (or any language capable of consuming the WSDL so I need to figure out how to create this request from scratch)

Is this even possible?
For example how are these GUID values generated? (Example: messageId & pretty much everything in the Signature node)

Its looking like I might be better off just proxying the request through a .NET client.

Comment: I'm not sure if the title to this question is accurate.  I have a good bit of WCF experience but never have done anything that requires this Signature Node.

Comment: `Its looking like I might be better off just proxying the request through a .NET client.` I would go that way....

Comment: Yea, I just wondering if its even possible in any framework other than .NET?  It would be nice to be able "pass the buck" back to their developers because there system is not compatible with ours.

Comment: NSjonas, Of course it is possible, at the end, it is a *http post* request containing an xml/soap object. But implementing it may  be painful. A restful API with json would be more easy to code for non-.Net clients(and your service provider can handle it only with some configuration changes without changing the code(Nice part of WCF))

Comment: @L.B Yes of course anything is possible. I wanted to know, generally, what it would require to recreate the request (Example: porting the entire .NET security model). I basically don't want to tell them its impossible and then eat my words later if there is actually a reasonable solution I'm just not aware of.

Comment: NSjonas, Just ask them for a sample (for ex,) java client and let them to think about how they torture the non-.net clients. Also you can post them google,twitter,facebook APIs to show how people does it correctly.

Comment: Thats a great idea @L.B.